# На чем проще написать desktop приложение - С# или NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, wpf, node.js, html5, desktop

Я делаю приложения на C# WPF, но давно хотелось писать десктопные приложения с html/css разметкой.
Сейчас читаю статьи по NW.js и Electron и много положительных отзывов . А про WPF много статей, что он вымирает.
Что Вы посоветуете для десктопной разработки и можете ссылки кинуть?
Что б и быстро работало и желательно на html/css/javascript.

Comment: Сам `microsoft` написал один из лучших редакторов кода на сегодняшний день с использованием `Electron`, который представляет из себя совокупность `Chromium` и `nodejs`.  

Что можно сказать об этой технологии.. Создание приложения доставит в большей части удовольствие за счет легкого создания клиентской части с использованием последних технологий, коими являются `sass`, `jade`, `reactjs` или `angular2` + `typescript` . А так же `express`, `koa`, `socket.io`  или нативные соккеты и огромное количество БД + `orm` к ним на серверной стороне.

Но есть и ложка дегтя - это жутко низкая скорость

Comment: К сожалению все приложения, в том числе и ранее упомянутые, очень медленные, постоянно тормозят и вызывают чувства, что приложение словно мед имеет определенную тягучесть, которая изрядно напрягает.

Но все зависит от размера приложения. До среднего размера, лично я бы предпочел создать на `Electron`, но не доверил бы это новичку. Ведь `js`, в особенности `nodejs` очень копризны и я очень часто встречаю, когда опытные программисты допускаю ситуации из-за которых происходят утечки.

Comment: Приехали... Подключите любой WebBrowser Engine, да хотя бы тот же WebKit.Net и пишите графический интерфейс на Html/Css/JS сколько влезет(долго, нудно, без автоматизации). В С++ это еще с ~2000 года используют, что Вам мешает? Как по мне связка WPF+Blend достаточно мощная для десктопных приложений.